# Centos 7 does not boot any more

Tags: centos, rescue

I deinstalled SOME VESA drivers from my CentOS 7 system.

Now it doesn't boot any more.

**What can I do now?**

Should I boot with no graphical interface? And then? I can't reinstall the system from scratch because I would lose important programs and configuration. Should I reinstall only the gnome graphical environmental?

Can I do this while being connected to a wireless in the non graphical environment?

Comment: Vesa drivers aren't used very deeply today. You used probably some different one.

Comment: Thank by the way now centos does not boot properly it goes in a loop.. Should I reinstall the standard gnome group?

Answer (score 0):

Try a

`yum history`

And look at the packages you uninstalled, then do a

```
yum history undo ID
```

Wher ID is the number of the command you uninstalled the VESA drivers

Comment: Thanks a lot, user21, but should I enter in the systemd.unit multi user? And from there I should use yum history?

Comment: No, enter theese 2 commands in a terminal as root. Then simply reboot the system